# Leaving Photon room immediately after RPC

Tags: photon

How does Photon handle a player leaving a room immediately after issuing a RPC? Does the RPC reach the targeted players?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RPCs are sent reliably independent from the transport protocol used.
RPCs are RaiseEvent operation calls under the hood.
The client sends RaiseEvent operation request to the relay server (Game Server) then the relay server will send a custom event to the target active actors if any.

Since this operation request is sent reliably, the client can retry sending it if no ack is received from the server after some time. However, if the client leaves the room, it will switch servers (disconnect from the Game Server and connects to the Master Server). So the retry attempts may be skipped in this case.

If the RaiseEvent operation request successfully reaches the server then the RPC reaching the target will be the responsibility of the server only.